# get json_encode from codeigniter controller to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a problem in jQuery, on how to get data from my [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) controller to jQuery function.

I am having a progress bar in jQuery and i need the value of the progress bar will be depend on the output of the controller; i use **[json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** in controller.

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: //get value from the controller json_encode
      });
  });
```

**Controller**

```
public function countScoreCh(){
$id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
$data['getScore'] = $this->lawmodel->battleUserID($id);
foreach($data['getScore'] as $row){
    $scoreCH = $row->challengerScore;
    echo json_encode(
    array(
    'scoreCH' => $scoreCH,
            )
        );
}
```

}

the progress bar function will be something like this.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value:   //jsn.scoreCH value
      });
  });
```

Is there's a possible way of doing it? I don't know if using json_encode is the correct way. But any solution will do..:)

Thanks..

Comment: AJAX is what ya need!

Comment: @Zurreal: What  controller do you mean? This `$id = $this->session->userdata('userID');` could be php code. Are you using php?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: yeah..im using PHP with COdeigniter Framework..xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your controller doesnt produce the valid json. since it would produce a json string like this one :

```
{scoreCH:<SomeValue>}{ScoreCH:<SomeValue>}{ScoreCH:<Somevalue>}
```

It would be better if you put the set of ScoreCH value inside some "json wrapper" so you should modify you controller to create a temporary variable that contain all your values from the model like this one :

```
public function countScoreCh(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $data['getScore'] = $this->lawmodel->battleUserID($id);
    // Here is "my hack"
    $output = array(); // it will wrap all of your value
    foreach($data['getScore'] as $row){
          unset($temp); // Release the contained value of the variable from the last loop
          $temp = array();

          // It guess your client side will need the id to extract, and distinguish the ScoreCH data
          $temp['id_of_ScoreCH'] = $row->id;
          $temp['ScoreCH'] = $row->ScoreCH;

          array_push($output,$temp);
    }
    // Now the $output supposed to be a two dimensional array looks like this one
    // array(
    //    [0]=>array("id_of_ScoreCH"=>SomeID,"ScoreCH"=>SomeValue),
    //    [1]=>array("id_of_ScoreCH"=>SomeID,"ScoreCH"=>SomeValue),
    //    [2]=>array("id_of_ScoreCH"=>SomeID,"ScoreCH"=>SomeValue)
    //   );

    // Then emit the wrapped value It would produce array of object JSON
    // Dont forget to put the header format
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($output);
 }
```

Next on your client side (HTML) use the `JSON.parse(<string_retrieved_from_controller>)` like this one :

```
$.ajax({
    url:<your_controller_name/you_method_name>,
    data: <your_specific_data_you_want_to_pass_to_the_server>,
    method:<post/get>
    success:function(retrieved_data){
         // Your code here.. use something like this
         var Obj = JSON.parse(retrieved_data)

         // Since your controller produce array of object you can access the value by using this one :
         for(var a=0; a< Obj.length; a++){
              alert("the value with id : " + Obj.id_of_scoreCH + "is " + Obj.ScoreCH);
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: wow..its really work..i find it a little bit hard at first..but i got it anyway..:) thanks!!